# Horizontal scrolling inside a div

Tags: html, css

I need to have a horizontal scroller of `divs` which each `div` is basically an image uploader.

I have this HTML/CSS code:

```css
.whiteBox {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  padding-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.1), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.1);
  overflow: auto;
}

.uploadBox {
  width: 90vw;
}

.uploader {
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  width: 39vw;
  height: 25vh;
  margin-left: 4vw;
  margin-top: 4vw;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2);
  float: left;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploadBox whiteBox">
  <h1 class="fontTitle"> Upload Your Photos</h1>
  <hr>

  <div class="uploader boxCorners">
    <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview1" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);">
      <input type="file" id="imageUpload1">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="uploader boxCorners">
    <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
      <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- many more divs like those goes here.. -->
</div>
```

I need to get this :

[image]

Where the Yellow **is a box(div) inside the screen** (not the screen )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the upload `buttons` inside a `div` and give `div` these properties `overflow-x: scroll;` `display:flex;`

```css
.whiteBox
{
  background-color:  rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
  padding-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.1), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.1);
}

.scroller{
      overflow-x: scroll;
      display:flex;
}

.uploadBox
{
   width: 90vw;
}

.uploader
{

  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
      width: 52vw;
  height: 25vh;
  margin-left:4vw;
  margin-top: 4vw;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2);
  float: left;
  max-height: 200px;


}
```

```html
<div class="uploadBox whiteBox">
                <h1 class="fontTitle" > Upload Your Photos</h1>
                <hr>
<div class="scroller">


                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview1" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload1">
                       </div>
                </div>


                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the title will also scroll left for some reason even that its outside the scroller div.

Comment: @Curnelious remove `overflow: auto;` from `.whiteBox`

Comment: thanks, if i do that, the whole page and background will scroll left.. even worse

Comment: you have run the snippet above?Its it working accordingly?

Comment: yours works mine not. Will check why, altough its the same

Comment: Well, if I do it like yours it will put all the "uploaders" inside the screen and they will turn to be smaller in width to fit the scroller width, if I try to make them wider it will not affect- they stay small.

Comment: by giving width to the `uploaders` their width will remain the same and scroller will be added, no matter how many loader you will going to have

Comment: thank you. but I would like to be able to set their width to 50%, then to scroll right, exactly like the image i show on the question .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189718/discussion-between-abdul-basit-and-curnelious).

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```css
.whiteBox
{
  background-color:  rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.1), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.1);
}

.uploadBox
{
   display: flex;
}

.uploader
{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
  width: 39vw;
  height: 25vh;
  margin-left:4vw;
  margin-top: 4vw;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.2);
  float: left;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fontTitle" > Upload Your Photos</h1>
<div class="uploadBox whiteBox">
                <hr>

                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview1" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload1">
                       </div>
                </div>


                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="uploader boxCorners">
                       <div class="imagePreview boxCorners" id="imagePreview2" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);">
                       <input type="file" id="imageUpload2">
                       </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

**Achieved by the following modifications of your code:**

- Move `h1` outside of `.uploadBox`
- Remove `width` from `.uploadBox`, add `display: flex;` instead
- Add `flex: 0 0 auto;` on `.uploader`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this style mentioned class

```
.uploadBox {display: flex;overflow-x: scroll;}
```

Comment: That way `h1` will not stay above the `.uploaders`.